# Select element which has just been created

Tags: jquery

I have come across a problem when working with JSON and making structured content after that.

The thing is that the only HTML of a panel is this:

```
<div class="users">
            <center>loading</center>
            <script>update_users();</script>
        </div>
```

But after downloading the information with JSON it ends up with something like that:

```
<div class="users">
<p class="name">User1</p>
<div class="detailed">
    <span>Entry1: value1</span>
</div>
</div>
```

The thing is that, in my case for example, I want detailed to be `toggle();` as `display:none` should be the default value but Jquery doesn't want to select that new content.

```
//does work
  $(".users").click(function(){
            $(".users .detailed").toggle();
        });

//doesn't work
    $(".users .name").click(function(){
            $(".users .detailed").toggle();
        });
```

How can I solve the problem that Jquery doesn't work to select new content inserted to the page?

Comment: You have to apply the click event after you load the content.

Comment: I think attaching a `.on('click')` handler will solve this.

Comment: When is this js fired?

Comment: @Hello-World You aren't adding any extra HTML. You are just simply selecting form your base one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that new content you need event delegation

```
$(document).on('click',".users .name",function(){
     $(".users .detailed").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `.live()` method, read something about that.
I can advise you to use:

```
$.find(".users .name").click(function(){
            $(".users .detailed").toggle();
        });
```

Or you can bind some function using `.on("click", yourfunction);`

Comment: the .live() method has been deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9

Comment: @user1671639 my comment is in it's place, read the first line of the answer

Comment: I wrote, that there is such method, but advised to use another one or newer .on(). So read carefully before commenting. Thanks.

Comment: And i merely clarified that the method is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

use `on`

```
$(document).on('click',".users .name",function(){
     $(".users .detailed").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are dynamically creating the `.name` paragraph simple `.click()` will not work for it. You have to use `.on()` method

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.name' ,function(){
   $(".detailed").toggle();
});
```

And technically if you have more than 1 users than the above approach will not work as it will toggle all the elements having `.detailed` class you should try this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.name' ,function(){
   $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2QkFz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".users .name").unbind();
```

unbind then rebind